# Remove irc whowas history

Tags: authentication, irc

I registered a "foo" account on freenode irc server.
When I run

```
/whowas foo
```

I can see the last login of "foo" user and public IP. I want to remove that information and I have tried to connect/disconnect many times but all logins are tracked.

1. How many of such logins are tracked? (better: how many login/logout I must do to remove some entry?)
2. Is there a way to remove login history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On all IRC servers I've seen, the `WHOWAS` information is stored in memory. It will be removed automatically after a short amount of time (on the order of hours, typically). The information is updated every time you log out, so logging in and logging out will *extend* its lifespan.

Some IRC services keep extended information about the last hostname a user logged in with, which can usually be viewed with `/msg NickServ INFO <yournick>`. This data is usually kept until the nickname expires and is unregistered. The Rizon IRC network [behaves this way](https://wiki.rizon.net/index.php?title=Services_Commands#Nick_information). Getting rid of this information requires logging in with a hostname that you do not mind being public.

The behavior of the `WHOWAS` command is defined in [RFC 1459 § 4.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-4.5.3).